# Debugging JS in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

For apps that were running in simulator, I was able to debug Javascript on Safari till yesterday night. However, something happened today and I am not able to do it.

I tried it on 2 other laptops as well and it is not working on them as well.

1. I have tied resetting simulator, restarting Mac, updating everything
2. I have tried getting other projects from github to ensure there is nothing wrong in my current project - did not work
3. Below is how it looks in Safari
   [image]

Is there something else that I can try to get it working again?

Comment: Restart the safari ! And run the project!  or run the project and  restart the safari!

Comment: Already tried these combinations...